# Facebook FQL query not working as expected -- possibly due to language issues?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a question regarding facebook FQL and it expected behavior. I have a specific example to share.

I am querying the FacebookJapan (id: 365989369023) Page with this fql query in the fql console:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = 365989369023
```

When doing this query, I receive back posts that aren't even written by facebookJapan (can confirm with the actor_id and I can't even find these posts on FacebookJapan's Page.

However, when explicitly writing out:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = 365989369023 AND actor_id = 365989369023
```

I actually get the posts that I would expect and mirrors the actual FacebookJapan's page.

However, this isn't an ideal solution because I'm querying other Pages and would like to grab all the posts and not just those with the same actor_id as the Page id itself.

Am I doing something wrong? I really can't find anything wrong with the first FQL statement. If you have time, I would kindly ask to confirm if things aren't working right with this particular query and Page id. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query seems fine to me, what exactly is the problem? My understanding of the stream table is that it should be returning posts on the page's wall regardless of who posted them - is that not what ordinarily happens?

Comment: Hi, I mean to say that both queries work, but the first queries results are wrong.

For example, if I use the first query and I look at the fql console, I see results that are entirely different from what is on the actual Page at http://www.facebook.com/FacebookJapan .  On the facebook.com/FacebookJapan page, all of the posts are written by FacebookJapan.  That is to say, the source_id and the actor_id are the same (365989369023)

However, with the first query, you can see that the results show actor_ids that are not the source_ids.

Comment: The default view of posts on Facebook Japan is 'posts by Facebook Japan', if you click the link beside that (just below the place where you'd write on the wall) marked 'Everyone (Most recent)' it'll show you the other posts